# Automake reuse common files

Tags: c++, automake

I am using automake to build several projects in C++ and the projects will have quite some files in common. I have one git repository for each of the projects and one repository for the common files. Each project is going to be distributed as a separate package.

My file structure looks something like this:

`project_1
   src
   include
project_2
   src
   include
common_files
   src
   include`

How should I setup automake within each project and within the common_files to reflect this structure and make each of the projects possible to distribute?
Many thanks for suggestions.

/M

Comment: It is considered that common files can be used as a static or shared library, so that can you add this library as a dependency for the rest of the projects. 2. I can suggest you to switch to cmake instead of  atomake/atoconf if you not yet started, you will spend twice less time, with the same or better result.

Comment: Thanks! I am already using automake. Should I build the common_files library from within each project, that is, should I add the common_files folder to the SUBDIRS of the Makefile.am of for example project_1? If I do that common_files will not compile as its "top_builddir" gets set to a folder above project_1, project_2 and common_files.

Comment: you can build it only once, and then add it to the linker for each sub-project. And don't forget to add includes for the sub projects compiler search path. i.e. something like `gcc -Icommon_files/include` and `ld -Lcommon_files/lib -lcommon`